# DNS is available after boot or netplan change but fails quickly

Tags: networking

I have a lab ubuntu server running 20.04 which was upgraded from 18.04 which was upgraded from 14.04. It's had a lot of network configuration along the way and I am a hobbyist/novice.

My /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml is very simple.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

If I run a `sudo netplan apply` on that then I can happily ping google.com for a short time but after a minute or so I start getting temporary DNS resolution errors. I've tried it with and without NetworkManager specified.

My plan is to rebuild this box with a fresh 20.04 but I'd like to be able to copy some files across the network and open a couple of apps via http and make note of a couple of things first.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Update: I found my systemd-resolved.service wasn't running which was weird cuz it wasn't running earlier and I'd enabled it. DNS is working again (for now). I'm concerned the service will stop again.

Comment: I believe it is `version: 2` not "true". Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That was a typo when I put it here. It's actually 2.

Comment: I believe you also need: `renderer: networkd` Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/dhcp.yaml`